# Import a table data into Mysql from MSSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, data-migration

I want to export the table from SQL Server 2005 database to Mysql database.

both the servers are in the same network.
Can someone please explain how to do it.

Comment: You may need a convertion/migration from SQL Server to MySql not an export operation

Comment: Thanks @CagCak, Please let me know if you know any tool that does the job

Comment: You may follow these instructions: http://eitwebguru.com/how-to-convertmigratemovecopy-mssql-database-to-mysql-database/